# How to define a key in xslt in which "match" and "use" attributes are both chindren of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

Example: For an xml like this,

```
<persons>
  <person name="Tarzan" id="050676"/>
  <person name="Donald" id="070754"/>
  <person name="Dolly" id="231256"/>
</persons>
```

I can write

```
<xsl:key name="person-by-id" match="person" use="@id"/>
```

to define a key

If my xml structure is,

```
<persons>
  <person>
   <name>Tarzan</name>
   <id>050676</id>
  </person>
  <person>
   <name>Donald</name>
   <id>070754</id>
  </person>
  <person>
   <name>Dolly</name>
   <id>231256</id>
  </person>
</persons>
```

How will i give values for match and use?

```
<xsl:key name="person-by-id" match="???" use="???"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `use` value is simply the path relative to the node indicated in `match`, so in the case of that XML, it would be:

```
<xsl:key name="person-by-id" match="person" use="id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:key name="person-by-id" match="/persons/person" use="id"/>
```

OR

```
<xsl:key name="person-by-id" match="person" use="id"/>
```

the match will start from the top and match with the word you defined.